# Car keeps running hot

Tags: pontiac, cooling, vibe

I replaced the thermostat on my 2008 Pontiac vibe and I I’ve bled the cooling system 5 or 6 times and it’s still running hot it’s not the water pump it’s not leaking no water in the oil wat else could it be

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the overheating the reason you changed out the thermostat in the first place?

Comment: Hello. So many possible answers. Blocked radiator? Faulty temperature gauge / sender? (is the engine actually getting hot, or does it just say it is?). You say it's not the water pump - mind giving a bit more background info? because it sounds like you've had a fiddle or two with the cooling system as i read it :)

Comment: No I don’t think the engine is actually getting hot cause I drove it about 10 miles with the heat hand all the way up then all of a sudden it dropped down to where it’s supposed to be and I’ve never had any trouble with anything until I changed my thermostat no water in the oil no water coming out the tail pipe spark plugs are good and I just bled the system again and still doing it when I start driving but when I stop and put it in park my temperature hand starts to go down

Comment: How did you determine it is running hot?